# asp.net webforms with js

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How do you use a normal js script with normal html code in a webform? I have this code below but when it runs the div tags display on the page for two seconds then they disappear. When checking the elements i see that the div tag is being assigned the class aspNetHidden. How can i fix this?

HTML code:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 9</div>
    <img src="Images/slide1.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 9</div>
    <img src="Images/slide2.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 9</div>
    <img src="Images/slide3.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 9</div>
    <img src="Images/slide4.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 9</div>
    <img src="Images/slide5.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">6 / 9</div>
    <img src="Images/slide6.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">7 / 9</div>
    <img src="Images/slide7.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">8 / 9</div>
    <img src="Images/slide8.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">9 / 9</div>
    <img src="Images/slide9.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
```

js Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);

        // Next/previous controls
        function plusSlides(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }

        // Thumbnail image controls
        function currentSlide(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        }

        function showSlides(n) {
          var i;
          var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
          var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
          if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
          if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
          for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
              slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
          }
          for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
              dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }
          slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
          dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
        }
    </script>
```

If relevant, the css code:

```
    <style>
        * {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your code segments within the content tags, I just tried and it worked. refer the code below. Simply you can create a new web application with site.master files and you can add your code segments in the aspx file

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<div class="slideshow-container">

    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 9</div>
        <img src="Images/slide1.png" style="width: 100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 9</div>
        <img src="Images/slide2.png" style="width: 100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 9</div>
        <img src="Images/slide3.png" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">4 / 9</div>
        <img src="Images/slide4.png" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">5 / 9</div>
        <img src="Images/slide5.png" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">6 / 9</div>
        <img src="Images/slide6.png" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">7 / 9</div>
        <img src="Images/slide7.png" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">8 / 9</div>
        <img src="Images/slide8.png" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">9 / 9</div>
        <img src="Images/slide9.png" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    // Next/previous controls
    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    // Thumbnail image controls
    function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
        if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    }
</script>

<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    /* Slideshow container */
    .slideshow-container {
        max-width: 1000px;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
    }

    /* Hide the images by default */
    .mySlides {
        display: none;
    }

    /* Next & previous buttons */
    .prev, .next {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: -22px;
        padding: 16px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 18px;
        transition: 0.6s ease;
        border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
        user-select: none;
    }

    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
        right: 0;
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }

        /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
        .prev:hover, .next:hover {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        }

    /* Caption text */
    .text {
        color: #f2f2f2;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
    .numbertext {
        color: #f2f2f2;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }

    /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
    .dot {
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 15px;
        width: 15px;
        margin: 0 2px;
        background-color: #bbb;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    }

        .active, .dot:hover {
            background-color: #717171;
        }

    /* Fading animation */
    .fade {
        -webkit-animation-name: fade;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
        animation-name: fade;
        animation-duration: 1.5s;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fade {
        from {
            opacity: .4;
        }

        to {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    @keyframes fade {
        from {
            opacity: .4;
        }

        to {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it turns out it was just a css error, the fade was kicking in before the code could run. just remove fade from all the tags and it works.